# can firestore be used for company internal app?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I hope this is still programming related, as SuperUser doesn't seem the appropriate place.

Im developing an app (its already working with a simple json backend) for my company (we are just 2 guys) on android , we go into our clients companies, record specific data at controll points with the app.

But i would like to use an online db instead becasue id like to create a website login for our clients where thez can see the data we recorded.

But
A) i dont even know if firestore can be used for apps outside the google app store or if i breach the usage cases of firestore. am i even allowed to use firestore for a company internal app?

and
B) anyone can apparently register to our firestore, hackers or naggers could just spam the auth function on the webinterface even though i only want the few accounts of our clients to be able to register (i could do that by hand in the cloud firestore console). How to prevent that?

is there a good alternative to firestore ???

the cool thing about firestore is that even if our has no internet connection itll still upload the data with 100% certainty even after reboots and app crashes.

thanx everybody , i know this isnt a real programming question but i searched for days and cant find anything useful , so i need you pros help here

Answer (score 1):

A. This is covered in the "Terms of Service" - https://firebase.google.com/terms/

B. You could create a pass key ("123abc"), give that pass key to your clients, which only when entered would send the Auth service request from the web page, and log them
You should probably make a different pass key for each client, this way you can delete the pass key in case you no longer work with that client.

Comment: on web you could just open the developer tool and spam
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword("random@random.com", "random"). 
thats my concern. 

what do you mean by passkey ? password is set when i enter a new user in the firebase console

Comment: This is more of an app issue then fireBase, but if your services are "Private" then you shouldn't be able to call them from the developer tool.
The only way of registering a new user should be either by you from the fireBase site, or from a form you created in the UI
in the 2nd case before sending the register form, make a pop up window which require a pin code

Comment: ahh ok so i would need it to develop with angular for example?, and cannot just program the webinterface with simple html/js ? 

the android app is made with ionic cli and angular .. but i thought for the web i´d just use simpe html/js .. hmm , im pretty new to all this sorry